# RTK Query manual cache updates for list and single queries

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've been working with RTK Query for a short time. I'm currently trying to find a solution to the following problem.

I have defined the following API.

```
export const teamApi = coreApi.injectEndpoints({
  overrideExisting: false,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
       getPlayerById: builder.query<Player, GetPlayerByIdQueryArgs>({
      query: ({ playerId }) => `profiles/${playerId}`,
    }),
    getTeamSquadById: builder.query<Squad, GetTeamSquadByIdQueryArgs>({
      query: ({ teamId }) => `teams/${teamId}/squad`,
      onQueryStarted: async (
        { teamId },
        { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }
      ) => {
        const { data } = await queryFulfilled;

        await Promise.all(
          data.players.map((player) =>
            dispatch(
              teamFupaApi.util.upsertQueryData(
                "getPlayerById",
                { playerId: player.slug },
                player
              )
            )
          )
        );
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

If I now request a team, all players are already included in the answer. That's why I'm trying to create the cache entry for the 'getPlayerById' query directly.

If I try to use this in my components, requests are still made and the cache entries are not used.

```
const Team: FunctionComponent<TeamProps> = ({ teamId }) => {
  const { data, isSuccess } = useGetTeamSquadByIdQuery({ teamId: teamId });

  if (!isSuccess)
    return (
      <Container>
        <CircularProgress />
      </Container>
    );

  return (
    <Container>
      {data.players.map((player) => (
        <PlayerCard playerId={player.slug} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

const PlayerCard: FunctionComponent<PlayerCardProps> = ({ playerId }) => {
  const { data, isSuccess } = useGetPlayerByIdQuery({ playerId: playerId });

  if (!isSuccess) return <CircularProgress />;

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardMedia image={data.image.path} />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5">
          {data.firstName} {data.lastName}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

If I build the whole thing with a timeout, the cache entries are used. Is there a timing problem? Maybe there is a general pattern to solve this better.

```
const Team: FunctionComponent<TeamProps> = ({ teamId }) => {
  const { data, isSuccess } = useGetTeamSquadByIdQuery({ teamId: teamId });
  const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isSuccess) return;
    setTimeout(() => setShowList(true), 5000);
  }, [isSuccess]);

  if (!isSuccess || !showList)
    return (
      <Container>
        <CircularProgress />
      </Container>
    );

  return (
    <Container>
      {data.players.map((player) => (
        <PlayerCard playerId={player.slug} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Many thanks for your help.